# Left-inverse to $n$th prime function

Tags: number-theory

Consider the function
$$p:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$$
which gives the $n$th prime. ($p(1)=2$, $p(2)=3$, etc.) Let
$$r:\mathbb{N}_{\ge 2}\to\mathbb{N}$$
be the non-decreasing left-inverse of $p$, i.e. for all $x\in\mathbb{N}$, $r(x)$ outputs $n$ where $p(n)$ is largest prime smaller less than or equal to $x$. For example,
$$r(2)=1,\quad r(3)=2,\quad r(4)=2,\quad r(5)=3,\quad r(6)=3,\quad r(7)=4...$$
Is there a known asymptotic behaviour of $r(x)$ as $x\to \infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that your $r(x)$ is precisely the [prime-counting function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function), usually denoted $\pi(x)$. There are two good asymptotic expressions for $\pi(x)$.

- The first one is a statement of the prime number theorem: $\pi(x)\sim\frac x{\ln x}$.
- The second one is known as the logarithmic integral: $\pi(x)\sim\operatorname{li}(x)=\int_0^x\frac1{\ln x}\ dx$.

The second expression is more accurate than the first.